# Error:Failed to open zip file

Tags: java

**Error:Failed to open zip file.**
Gradle 's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, I have download zip file manually and past it.But,not working.

Comment: How did you re-download the dependencies? And ensure the existing dependencies were replaced? E.g., sometimes it's easiest to just blow away the Maven repo and start over. If you know precisely what's failing (impossible to tell since you didn't provide much information) you can remove just that dependency from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

- Manually download

  Open your android studio root directory, and extract the zip to the
  gradle folder

  File->Settings->Build, Exectution, Deployment->Gradle and set "Gradle
  home" to point your new gradle-3.3 folder and Sync